# If $\sum_{i=0}^{N} a_i \approx 0$, can I say that $\sum a_i \approx a_j$, where $a_j$ is a one single element of the sum?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, approximation

I'm computing the convergence rate of an optimization algorithm. The vector of the update of the parameters is $\varepsilon_{j}^{k}$ ,where $j$ indicates the vector element and $k$ the iteration index. I've found that $\frac{\varepsilon_{j}^{k+1}}{\varepsilon_{j}^{k}}=1-\frac{\alpha}{\varepsilon_{j}^{k}}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\xi}\varepsilon_{\xi}^{k}$

To actually have a number for the convergence rate  I'd like to be able to make it without that sum so that I can actually get a number and not an expression. 
I happen to know that the elements of $\varepsilon$ are both positive and negative and their values are independent. So $\sum_{\xi}\varepsilon_{\xi}\approx0$ . If the first is true then also $\sum_{\xi;\;\xi\neq j}\varepsilon_{\xi}\approx0$ stands and, if the latter is true then $\sum_{\xi}\varepsilon_{\xi}\approx\varepsilon_{j}$. I'd truly like to do this, but it doesn't sound right. If I were able to do this, my original expression would simplify to $\frac{\varepsilon_{j}^{k+1}}{\varepsilon_{j}^{k}}=1-\frac{\alpha}{\varepsilon_{j}^{k}}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\xi}\varepsilon_{\xi}^{k}\approx1-\frac{\alpha}{N}\frac{\varepsilon_{j}}{\varepsilon_{j}}=1-\frac{\alpha}{N}$, which is finally a number that's easy to interpret as a convergence rate.

Comment: The remaining sum $\sum_{n\neq j} \epsilon_n$ is almost zero if you removed something almost zero, that is $\epsilon_j\approx 0$.

Comment: Well... The sum is almost 0 because I'm summing positive and negative numbers all of similar magnitude. Not because each $\varepsilon_j$ is close to $0$.

Comment: I'm making myself more clear : you begin with $\sum_{n} \epsilon_n\approx 0$ because you have such $\epsilon_n$ (eg $\epsilon_n$ iid with $P(\epsilon_1=\pm 1) = \frac{1}{2}$). But then you deduce that removing one term doesn't affect the whole sum, ie: is small. Well ok but that removed term must be very small, and which one is it ? every $j$ or just fixed one ? etc

Comment: It should work for each $j$. The term is not very small. It's the same magnitude as the others! So, what if instead of starting from the whole sum I start from the split one? The reason for this is that I want to analyse how the next step for one element depends on the  current one. And it happens to give me a nice expression.

Comment: It also depends on the range of summation. For example, $\epsilon_i$ iid with law $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,n)$ which can be very different from $\epsilon_1$ as $n$ grows larger.